# Get the data with max date and max and one more column in SAS

Tags: sql, oracle, sas, greatest-n-per-group

TableA

```
ID    LineNum   Date
123    12       30JAN2016
123    15       30JAN2016
123    21       25JAN2016
```

How to get the ID where DATE is MAX and LineNum for that particular date should be max,
in the above table  max date is 30JAN2016 and for that 15 is maximum,

Output should be:
123 15 30JAN2016

Comment: What's this got to do with SAS? For now I will remove the tag.

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: Tried the sub query as the first answer below but thought will have a easier solution.

Comment: Assuming your real data has records for multiple IDs, do you want to output one record per ID or just one record from the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ordering the data and choosing the first row.  In Oracle, this is traditionally written as:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*
      from tablea a
      order by date desc, linenum desc
     ) a
where rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can write this more simply as:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
order by date desc, linenum desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, assuming that your date variable is numeric, you could do a proc sort by id, date and linenum and then select the last record in a datastep.

```
proc sort data=in; by id date linenum; run;

data out;
 set in;
  by id;
   if last.id;
run;
```

This will give one row per `ID` with the `max` date and max `linenum`

Comment: This would output one record per ID. It's not clear to me if that is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

SAS proc sql:

```
proc sql;
   select * from have group by id having date=max(date) and linenum=max(linnum);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want it the maximum date for each ID, and this can be performed with the following query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select ID, max(Date) maxDate
     from table
     group by ID) a join (
     select ID, Date, max(LineNum) maxLineNum
     from   table
     group by ID, Date
) b
On a.ID = b.ID AND a.maxDate = b.Date
```

Explain:

1. You first select the maximum date for each ID (the first subquery).
2. You then select maximum line number for each ID and Date (second subquery).
3. By joining them, you will obtain the row with maximum date as well as maximum LineNum at the same time!